# Insert quote into string variable in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, string

Is there way of inserting a quote at the start and end into a string variable?

I have this variable say:

```
string="desktop/first folder"
```

If I echo this, it will display:

```
desktop/first folder
```

I need the string to be stored as:

```
"desktop/first folder"
```

Comment: I know the question is about `bash` but for POSIX compatible system where the string must contain both single and double quotes you have to mix between both without spaces in between. For example `string="single quote: ' double quote: "'"'" end of string"`. This works because quoted  strings next to each other are considered a single string and you can switch between single and double quote strings within those parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't do variable substitution, using single quotes as delimiters, so you can use double quotes in your string:

```
string='"desktop/first folder"'
```

Answer (score 13):

In bash you can use `\` as an escape character what whatever follows it. In your case, use it like this:

```
string="\"desktop/first folder\""
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case one needs to do variable substitution:

```
string='"'"$folder"'"'
```

The inner double quotes allow variable expansion, and each of the outer double quote is flanked by single quotes to "keep" them at their place.